# Return array after for loop in functions?

Tags: c++, arrays, for-loop

Consider this code:

```
# include <iostream>

class Array
{
private:
    int array[5];
public:
void getArray()
{
   for(int i = 0; i < 5; i++)
    {
        std::cin>>array[i];
        //std::cout<<array[i]<<std::endl; It would print array 0 to array 5
    }
}

void printArray()
{
    // How do I print array from index 0 - 5 
}

};
    

int main()
{
    Array a;
    a.getArray();
    a.printArray();
}
```

Can I use a for loop for to print the `printArray`? Or do I use a `return` for my function? Can use the array out of boundaries?

---

### Conclusion

I want to use the array at another function. Is it possible to do so?

Comment: why do you think accessing `array` in `getArray` would be any different from accessing it in `printArray` ?

Comment: If you din't have a class, objects or different functions, but all in the single `main` function, and you wanted to separate input and output, how would you do it then? Now what makes you think it would be different when you use different functions?

Answer (score 3):

Exactly like you have already written

```
void printArray()
{
    for (int i = 0; i < 5; i++)
    {
        std::cout<<array[i]<<std::endl;
    }
}
```

This is the point of class member variables like `array`. They are associated with an object (such as `a` in `main`), and persist from one method invocation to another for a given object.

Some suggestions to improve your code.

Firstly `printArray` doesn't change the `Array` object, so it should be declared as `const`

```
void printArray() const
{
    for (int i = 0; i < 5; i++)
    {
        std::cout<<array[i]<<std::endl;
    }
}
```

Secondly, use a range-based for loop. This loop works whatever the size of the array which is obviously a good thing

```
void printArray() const
{
    for (int a : array)
    {
        std::cout<<a<<std::endl;
    }
}
```

Comment: `const`  will make the code run faster, right?

Comment: @CPP_is_no_STANDARD No, not likely. It's there for type safety.

Comment: @CPP_is_no_STANDARD I think that's pretty unlikely, but it will let you call the method in a sitation where you have a const object. `const Array& x ...; x.printArray();` Unless printArray is const this code would not compile.